# Change label with conditional jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to change the label content with a jquery function. 
Label content has to change when my `carousel-item` with `id=3` has the `active` class. I'm using a bootstrap carousel component. Here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Biópolis</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- <script src="menu.js"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="pagina">

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-bot">
                <a class="navbar-brand nav-pos" href="#"> <img src="img/Logo biópolis ok calado.png"> </a>
            </nav>
```

Container of the label that I want to chage

```
            <div class="container text-center contenedor">
                <div class="centrar">
                    <label class="mayus" id="mayus">
                        Una comunidad interdisciplinaria
                    </label>
                    <label class="minus" id="minus">
                        construímos alternativas para desarrollos residenciales, urbanos y turísticos, responsables con la cultura, la naturaleza y el ser humano
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Other content of web page

```
            <div class="menu d-flex justify-content-right text-right">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">biópolis</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">arquitectura</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">planeación</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">equipo</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide bg-image" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" id="1">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/01_aerea_home.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" id="2">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Links/1_Club de playa_perspectiva.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" id="3">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Links/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" id="4">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Links/4.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" id="5">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Links/5.JPG" alt="Third slide">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" id="6">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Links/6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's my function to change the content of the label

```
<script>

$('#3').on('.active', function () {
    $('#mayus').text('Diseñamos un plan integral');
    $('#minus').text('en conjunto con nuestros clientes, cada producto es una solución que constribuye al desarrollo positivo del entorno');
} )        
    </script></body></html>
```

So, I can't figure it how to do the change.

Comment: `.active` is not an event, which is the first argument to `on()`.  What event(s), or logical changes, cause the element to get that class?

Comment: Is this "bootstrap carousel" you are using?  There are two events you could hook into documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events)

Comment: Do you mean, you are clicking the element?